# Django [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'MYSCHEMA.MyUnmanagedModel'

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-models, factory-boy

I'm running into this issue:

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'MYSCHEMA.MyUnmanagedModel'.

It's an unmanaged model, so I understand that I have to create the table manually ahead of time.

Here is the model:

```
class MyUnmanagedModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="ID", primary_key=True)
    end_year = models.IntegerField(db_column="endyear")
    grade = models.CharField(db_column="grade", max_length=2)
    enrollments = models.IntegerField(db_column="enrollments")

    class Meta(object):
        managed = False
        db_table = "[MYSCHEMA].[MyModelTable]"
```

I have ensured that my docker database contains the appropriate 'MYSCHEMA' with the table 'MyModelTable' and that it's built out appropriately with respect to the model (all the appropriate columns).

I'm using factory-boy to create the object: here is my Factory:

```
class MyUnmanagedModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUnmanagedModel
        database = "secondary_database"

    id = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n)
    end_year = 2021
    grade = 1
    enrollments = 1200
```

I use multiple databases in my project, the 'secondary_database' is the one that holds the database with the appropriate schema.

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "mssql",
        "NAME": os.environ.get("default_NAME"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("default_HOST"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("default_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("default_PASSWORD"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("default_PORT"),
        "OPTIONS": {
            "host_is_server": True,
            "driver": os.environ.get("ODBC_DRIVER"),
        },
    },
    "secondary_database": {
        "ENGINE": "mssql",
        "NAME": os.environ.get("secondary_NAME"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("secondary_HOST"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("secondary_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("secondary_PASSWORD"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("secondary_PORT"),
        "OPTIONS": {
            "host_is_server": True,
            "driver": os.environ.get("ODBC_DRIVER"),
        },
    },
```

Using DataGrip or Azure Data Studio, I can connect to the secondary_database, I can see the MYSCHEMA exists and I can confirm that the table 'MyModelTable' exists.

When I run `MyUnmanagedModelFactory()` is where I see the error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'MYSCHEMA.MyModelTable'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

Comment: My guess would be you are connecting to the wrong database, or you have created your objects in the wrong one.

Comment: I would think so, too. But I specify the database in the factory_boy model. So I'm a little lost as to where/why that might happen.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried using `db_table = "MYSCHEMA].[MyModelTable"`? ref: [Working with SQL Server in Django pt. II](http://nightlyclosures.com/2019/10/16/working-with-unmanaged-sql-server-in-django-pt-ii/) It seems like an awful work-around to me, though.

Comment: That's an interesting article - it seems a bit hacky to me; not a fix I want to try just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to set database connection extra "options" to "-c search_path=SCHEMA_NAME" with no effect.

Setting db_table = "SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME" per model solved the problem described above. set both correct SHEMA_NAME and TABLE_NAME vars.

Comment: Any luck here? I am experiencing a similar issue I am stuck on. My database is MSSQL (managed by my company and they do not want Django tables in there). I have connected fine. I can run inspectdb to generate models, but I get an error stating `invalid object name 'Django_session'`